# Grouping and transforming data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python and I want to transform a dataframe using pandas.

Original dataframe is:

```
A1,B1,C1,M
A1,B1,C1,HM
A2,B2,C2,M
A2,B2,C2,M
A3,B3,C3,
```

Target is:

```
A1,B1,C1,HM
A2,B2,C2,M
A3,B3,C3,
```

I will need to remove duplicates and calculate the last field (HM/M) based on the values A,B,C. I wonder how can I achieve this transofrmation.

Comment: How do you decide with one to drop between the first and the second row?

Comment: Whenever I have "HM" in a row, the final row will take this value. "HM" is stronger than "M".

Comment: And the rows are One string (e.g. `"A1,B1,C1,HM"`) or for cells, each with a string in it (e.g. `A1`|`B1`|`C1`|`HM`) ?

Comment: The rows are with multiple cells of different types (string, float, datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can `sort_values` and just pick the `first()` of each `group` since M is ordered after HM

```
df.sort_values(['A','B','C','H']).groupby(['A','B','C']).first()
```

```
    A   B   C   H
0   A1  B1  C1  HM
1   A2  B2  C2  M
2   A3  B3  C3  NaN
```